# git copy particular version of repository

Tags: git

I'm new to git so forgive me if this is a dumb question.
I have a git repository and I need to copy a particular revision of the repository to its own separate directory. The copied version doesn't need to be a git repository itself, I don't need or want the history or the .git folder, just what the repository looked like for a particular commit.

So say I do this:

```
mkdir blah
cd blah
git init
touch flim0
git add .
git commit -a -m "First commit"
touch flim1
git add .
git commit -a -m "Second commit"

mystery-command ~/some-folder 4be82b42cc91ac3801ad72036cec5f88b6a13bd7
```

Where 4be82b42cc91ac3801ad72036cec5f88b6a13bd7 is the hash of "First commit", I want ~/some-folder to be a directory that contains only the file flim0.

Is this easy/possible without having to clone the repository then checkout a particular revision then delete .git from the cloned repository?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
 git archive master >specificversion.tar
```

replace master by a commit identifier

If you want to immediately 'check it out', consider

```
 git archive master | (cd /tmp/exportlocation && tar x)
```

`git archive` (as usual) comes with [a load of other useful options](http://linux.die.net/man/1/git-archive)

Answer (score 0):

**Update**

It's better to use the [archive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5815104/git-copy-particular-version-of-repository/5815246#5815246) option mentioned by Sehe

---

What I would do is just checkout that particular version:

```
git checkout <commit-sha1>
```

And then just copy all the contents except for the .git dir

```
rcopy --exclude=.git . ~/some-folder/
```

And then you could do

```
git checkout master
```

to reset the repository to the master branch again.

Comment: This is twisted. The `archive` command is the right way to go.

Comment: Didn't know that option existed